# How can I set a breakpoint on memory allocation?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, gdb

I have been trying to find a memory leak in a server. I leave it running and use top command to inspect the VIRT memory size field on it's PID while I connect clients to it. I notice that every time I run something which connects to the server the field increases by about 5 MB suggesting there is a leak somewhere. I want to set a breakpoint in gdb on any call to operator new and connect a client to see if i see any calls to new from an unexpected backtrace that I haven't already correctly inspected for a corresponding delete. How does one set such a breakpoint?

I am on linux btw.

Comment: Most likely you can break at `malloc`, but breaking on memory allocation is a rather painful way to figure out what's happening. If you post what operating system your code is on, someone can make a suggestion that is relevant to you, but if you're on Linux, Valgrind is a great place to start.

Comment: True but the server doesn't ever stop until killed. And the idea was that after a certain point it should never call new from more than a handful of locations so I was thinking a breakpoint would be good to use. Not sure how valgrind would help here.

Comment: If the server truly never stops until forcefully killed, you should provide a way to ask the program to terminate gracefully -- ideally in a manner that has it free/delete everything it's allocated. This will let valgrind be most helpful. Short of that, investigate malloc hooks for a way that's still better than a breakpoint (but again, breaking on malloc, if installed after legitimate mallocs have stopped, will let you find the call).

Comment: except it is not getting called after i say "break malloc" and this is what i cant figure out as I thought that would set the desired breakpoint

Comment: Perhaps the problem is not an unexpected call to `new` then ;) We're getting a bit long in comments (comment "chat" isn't really appropriate), but you might consider creating a malloc hook and logging every allocation that is made (as well as a free hook and logging frees).